# ¿Es posible hacer un JFrame con bordes redondeados en Java?

Tags: java

Estuve investigando y por lo que vi se podia hacer con AWTUtilities, pero según he visto esto ya no esta disponible.

Queria ver si me podian guiar, saludos.